# Problem writing a panda data frame to sql developer

Tags: python, pandas, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have been trying to write a panda dataframe from jupyter notebook (using to_sql) to sql developer. I did the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import cx_Oracle
from sqlalchemy import types, create_engine
df = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/TOSHIBA/Downloads/Pandas Hub/Pandas_data//survey_results_public.csv')
engine = create_engine('oracle+cx_oracle://hr:123456@localhost/orcl')
df.to_sql('sample_table',engine)
```

Upon execution, I get this error:

"UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 3-12: character maps to undefined".

When I checked my Sql developer, the sample_table is found created with all headings of Panda Dataframe intact but WITHOUT rows or row contents.

I went through previous answers in a hope to get a solution. But, none were of much help as my problem remains the same.

Would anyone help me in sorting out this issue. I am quite confused what went wrong here.

Comment: I think you meant 'writing a data frame to Oracle DB so I can view the data in SQL Developer'

Answer (score 0):

If you are using cx_Oracle 7 or earlier, then set your encoding to UTF-8 when connecting:

From [the SQLAlchemy doc](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/dialects/oracle.html):

```
engine = create_engine("oracle+cx_oracle://scott:tiger@oracle1120/?encoding=UTF-8&nencoding=UTF-8")
```

If you have upgraded to cx_Oracle 8, then the default is already UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

your data may have values greater than ASCII(128), try the following and this may help.
os.environ['NLS_LANG']= 'AMERICAN_AMERICA.AL32UTF8'

thanks